# Boosted trees and Variable Interactions in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, gradient-descent

How can one see in a Boosted trees classification model for machine learning (adaboost), which variables interact with each other and how much? I would like to make use of this in R gbm package if possible.

Comment: A tree is all interactions! The moment you specify that you tree has more than one node, the next leaf is using a different variable and that's the interaction.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the interaction between input variables, you can use any package like lm. http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-regression-with-interaction-variables/

Answer (score 1):

You can use ?interact.gbm. See also [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141391/4907) cross-validated question, which directs to [a vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dismo/vignettes/brt.pdf) of a related technique from the package *dismo*.

In general, these interactions may not necessarily agree with the interaction terms estimated in a linear model.